# BufferedReader in Socket Programming

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream, bufferedreader

When i am trying to send an input from a client, if i don't concat "\r\n" at the end of the string, my inputstream waits forever. I have seen various similar posts but couldn't find a proper solution. My code is as follows:

```
public void run() {
    
    PrintWriter out = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        String line;

        if (in.ready()) {
            if ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Received from client: " + line);
                out.write("Echoing: " + line);
                out.flush();
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        out.close();
        try {
            in.close();
            clientSocket.close();
            System.out.println("Closing connection from " + socketAddress + ", #" + connectionId);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One factor of course being that `readLine()` returns the line without trailing line break (`\r\n`, `\n`, NEL char).  `out.write("\r\n");` is not bad.

Comment: I cannot modify code in client. I need a different approach in server side.

Comment: How does the client tell the server it has sent a complete message? Can you post the code of the client or the documentation for the communication protocol it uses?

Comment: The client code is in PHP, i wrote a simple script for testing purposes. The real device that will communicate with the server can only send raw bytes.                                                   `socket_write($socket, $message, strlen($message))`

Comment: How can the server know if it has received a complete `$message` or if it has to wait for more data from the client? Also please tag users with @ when you reply to somebody in comments or they don't get notified

Comment: @Joni what you say makes sense but i have another PHP Echoserver running and it works without sending any line termination char from the client. I'd prefer this task to be performed using Java though.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to read some of the data that was sent, use the `read(char[])` method instead of the `readLine` method. This method returns the number of characters it read as an `int`. Example:

```
     char[] buffer = new char[2000];
     int read;
     if ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            String line = new String(buffer, 0, read);
            System.out.println("Received from client: " + line);
            out.write("Echoing: " + line);
            out.flush();
      }
```

What you'll see happen next is that this code sometimes fails to read the entire message you send from PHP, or that two or more messages are read as one.

If you want to fix that:

This will never work, and it's not because of PHP or Java. You're using TCP, a stream oriented protocol. There is no guarantee that the message you write to the socket from the PHP program will arrive in one piece to the receiver. The message may be broken up and you need multiple socket function calls to read it. Or it may go the other direction, and a single call to `read` returns more than one message.

The solution is to add some kind of framing for the messages so that the receiver knows when it has a complete message. Always ending a message with a line break serves as framing, if messages themselves are single lines. Another solution is to ditch TCP and use a message oriented protocol (like UDP) instead, but that will come with its own complications.